# Unity How to get transform from Hashset<EnemyScript>

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a `Hashset` to which I add my enemies to. In the Enemy script in the `OnEnable` and `Disable` I add and remove from the `Hashset`. The `Hashset` is a public static so I can access the count of it by just `Debug.Log(Enemy.enemyTargets.Count);` to see the number increase and decrease.

How do I access the transform of the Hashset, I know hashset have no specific order and that is fine but I just want the transform of whichever object inside the Hashset.

Inside Enemy.cs script

```cs
public class Enemy: MonoBehaviour {
    public static readonly HashSet<Enemy> enemyTargets = new HashSet<Enemy>();

    private Transform _transform;
    public new Transform transform => _transform = _transform ? _transform : base.transform;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        enemyTargets .Add(this);
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        enemyTargets .Remove(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be the transform of a set of enemies? If it’s any of them then just grab the first one and get its transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `HashSet` has no `transform` but rather each `Enemy` has its own `.transform` reference.

Don't override that property but rather simply use

```c#
foreach(var enemy in Enemy.enemyTargets)
{ 
    var transform = enemy.transform;
    // use each transform
}
```

You can also simplify it with Linq

```c#
foreach(var transform in Enemy.enemyTargets.Select(enemy => enemy.transform)
{
    // use transform
}
```

Or you could add a property for it like

```c#
public static Transform[] enemyTargetTransforms => enemyTargets.Select(enemy => enemy.transform).ToArray();
```

Comment: thank you so much. What would be the best one to use, it would be 2. to use Linq right to keep performance high? I heard Hashsets are way faster than List because they don’t require so much work.

Comment: The performance depends a lot on what you do with it! `HashSet` is extremely fast when using `Contains`, but slower then a list for every `Add`. For iterating over the elements `HashSet`, `List` and `Array` perform all in `O(n)` so no difference. I'ld still stick to a `HashSet` just to make sure you have always unique values since it doesn't allow any duplicate elements

Comment: awesome so really any of those choices are the same just depends what I do with the hashsets that determines the speed of it?